# dynamically name textview after inflating android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, layout-inflater

I m inflating 4 linear layouts multiple times in a scroll view. Each layout has a title in its header. The code snippet is given below.

```
for(int j=0;j<qType.length;j++)
    {           
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams siz = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);;
        if(qType[j]==0)
        {               
            view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout1, main_layout,false);
            siz = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height/3);                                       
        }
        else if(qType[j]==1)
        {                
            view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout3, main_layout,false);
            siz = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height/3);
        }
        else if(qType[j]==2)
        {           
            view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout4, main_layout,false);
            siz = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height/3);
        }
        else if(qType[j]==3)
        {           
            view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout5, main_layout,false);
            siz = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height/2);
        }       

        siz.topMargin = 25;
        main_layout.addView(view1, siz);            
    }
    scroll_layout.addView(main_layout);
    scroll_layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.options_background);     
    setContentView(scroll_layout);
```

Now there is textview in each layout and i want to change the text of it. If i access them by findviewbyid and give settext, only the first instance is being changed, i want to change the textview on all occasions.

```
    for(int k=0;k<NumberQuestions.length;k++)
    {
        TextView number_title = (TextView)main_layout.findViewById(R.id.number_title);
        TextView mcq_title = (TextView)main_layout.findViewById(R.id.mcq_title);
        TextView comment_title = (TextView)main_layout.findViewById(R.id.comment_title);
        TextView cam_title = (TextView)main_layout.findViewById(R.id.cam_title);
        if(qType[k]==0)
        {               
            number_title.setTypeface(myriadpro_bold);
            number_title.setText(NumberQuestions[k]);

        }
        if(qType[k]==1)
        {
            comment_title.setTypeface(myriadpro_bold);
            comment_title.setText(NumberQuestions[k]);              
        }
        else if(qType[k]==2)
        {
            mcq_title.setTypeface(myriadpro_bold);
            mcq_title.setText(NumberQuestions[k]);              
        }
        else if(qType[k]==3)
        {
            cam_title.setTypeface(myriadpro_bold);
            cam_title.setText(NumberQuestions[k]);              
        }
```

Please help.

Comment: Where is the `TextView` you are referring to and where do you call `setText()`?

Comment: please paste your textview code

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I feel like you are trying to work against the Android Framework, as opposed to working with it. My suggestion is a tad bit of an overhaul, but I do feel like it is the correct way to go about things.

I would recommend using a ListView, since you are repeating the same format many times. A listview will typically have a container of objects of objects, and an adapter responsible for mapping an object to a particular row within the listview. When you change the data in the underlying container, you will call the callback `notifyDataSetChanged()` for your adapter to notify it that you changed the underlying data and alert it to update your listview.

2 great resources/tutorials from the android developer site:
ListView: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
Adapters: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

Answer (score 0):

probably the TextView `android: id` in all layouts are the same, thus explaining the behavior of the method findViewById always returns the first occurrence

Answer (score 0):

If i am right main_layout is a name view in your xml file.So You should use like this

```
 view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout1, main_layout,false);
 TextView tv = (TextView)main_layout.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

where tv is texview in layout1.xml